# How to add filtered ManyToMany Field Relation

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

Let's say;

```
#models.py

choices = (
    (1, Published),
    (0, Draft)
)

Class Question(models.Model):
    question =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.IntegerField(
        choices=choices, default=0)

class Survey(models.Model):
    question = ManytoManyField(Question)
```

So I want the Questions to be available for the many-to-many field if the status of the question is 1 or say Published

For that can we do that?

```
ManytoManyField(Question.objects.filter(status=1))
```

Or how I can achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all that you need is `limit_choices_to` attribute:
more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to

in your case:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    question = ManytoManyField(Question, limit_choices_to={'status':1} )
```